# Как правильно разделить двойное слово на байт в ассемблере?

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

Я использую TASM, пишу 16-битную программу. Хочу поделить переменную x, которая является двойным словом, на переменную y, являющуюся байтом и остаток от деления сохранить в z. Вот мой код:

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
    x   dd  53
    y   db  24
    z   dw  ?
.code
START:
    mov ax,@Data
    mov ds,ax
    xor ax,ax
    xor dx,dx

    mov dx,word ptr [x+2]
    mov ax,word ptr [x]
    mov bl,y
    mov bh,0
    div bx

    mov z, dx

    mov ah,4Ch
    int 21h
end START
```

Мой код работает нормально для небольших чисел, но если, например, попробовать разделить `FFFF FFFF` на `2`, то уже получается какая-то ерунда, в отладке при делении переходит по коду куда-то очень далеко. Впрочем, понятно почему: результат деления сохраняется в 2-х байтный регистр ax, а остаток - в регистр dx такого же размера. То есть результат просто не влазит.

Как правильно реализовать эту задачу?

Comment: вы точно не хотите (или не можете) использовать eax/edx. потому что да, результат такого деления не определен и трубуется что то не тривиальное что бы это обойти

Comment: @Mike, Да, я не могу использовать 32-битные регистры. Условие задачи требует использовать только 16-битные.

Comment: @Mike, большое спасибо, буду разбираться :)

Comment: @Mike, Благодарю за пояснения. Вы всегда помогали с непростыми задачами).

Comment: Нашел таки более простое решение, чем у меня вышло изначально. написал ответ. (правда к этому времени успел свой перловый вариант сам перевести на asm, запутанно конечно сильно :) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К сожалению команда деления у процессоров intel серии x86 вызывает переполнение, в случае если частное от деления DX:AX на небольшое значение в двубайтном регистре не влезает в предназначенный для этого регистр AX. Возникает исключение, которое обычно обрабатывает ОС, аварийно завершая программу.

Решением проблемы является предварительная проверка на то, что переполнение возникнет и выполнение деления по другому сценарию. Сначала делим старшую часть числа, поместив его при этом в ax, а dx обнулив, получаем старшую часть частного. Остаток от деления используем в качестве старшей части при следующей операции деления младшей части делимого.

```
    xor  cx, cx
    cmp  dx, bx    ; Старшая часть делимого меньше частного - переполнения не будет
    jbe  div2
    mov  cx, ax    ; Сохраняем младшую часть
    mov  ax, dx
    xor  dx, dx
    div  bx
    xchg cx, ax    ; AX=младшая часть делимого, CX=старшая часть частного
                   ; В DX остался остаток от деления
div2:
    div  bx
done:
    ; в сx:ax находится частное, в dx - остаток от деления
```